# Example sites that use LinkedIn's API equivalent of 'Facebook Connect'?

Tags: api, authentication, registration, linkedin-api

Anyone know of any example sites that use LinkedIn's API as sign-up/registration service... similar to how 'facebook connect' is used.  Can't seem to find many, if any, examples out there.  I wonder why.  Must be a good reason for the lack of sites adopting this method of authentication.

Comment: did you ever get a working example? I would love to do the same thing

Comment: https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/authentication

Comment: I've seen a couple more site use Linkedin Authentication, but surprisingly not many.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly a web site in the sense how you mean it, but the mobile application [Socially](http://www.sociallyapp.com/) launches LinkedIn's authentication page in the mobile browser to authenticate using the service with the application.